# Dropdown menu not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Code: http://pastebin.com/xPvbG9JF

I cannot get my dropdown menu to work at all. I'd prefer it to be able to be hovered over, but I can work on that later. I need functionality than I can move to "glamour"

Thanks

Comment: I have checked this code, Dropdown is working.

Comment: Hmm, not on my machine, odd.

Comment: Do you have `jQuery`? Does your console (F12 -> Console) show any errors? Also: Working Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Z7N7oayMpN. If you can paste it into pastebin, you can copy it to Bootply and have a working example.